# Error when redirecting from auth0 to netlify

Tags: react-router-v4, auth0, netlify

I have an application running on a subdomain via netlify.

```
    https://whatever.mydomain.fakedomain
```

I'm using react router v4, I'm using the `createBrowserHistory`

My callback url is set properly on auth0, but went it tries to redirect, it cannot find the route even if it is coming to `https://whatever.mydomain.com/callback?...`

If I change my application to work a main domain `https://mydomain.fakedomain` it works properly, I'm not sure what is the proper way to solve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using redirect via netlify, so basically, the solution to create a `netlify.toml` file with something like:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/callback"
  to = "https://whatever.mydomain.fakedomain"
  status = 200
```